# Can FFT be used to find drum solos/breaks in audio files?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft

Is it possible with FFT to find a drum solo, or a drum break, in an audio file? Is this something FFT is able to do and are there any resources online that could aid me with learning?

Comment: If you need just beat detection, you can pass your signal through low-pass FIR.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my question mentions nothing about beat detection.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question gives no clues on what exactly you want to do. Find position in audio stream when drum kicks in? Well, that's beat detection very much alike. Or do you want decompose audio to reconstruct the drum section sheet?

Comment: In most Jazz, and Rock music a drum beat plays throughout the track, but there are sections of the track where all the instruments are silent and a drummer will do a drum roll, or a short drum solo. I wan't to detect when this occurs.

Comment: All right. Do you think the frequency of beats will be somehow higher (or detectably different) during solo parts that the tune's global rhythm? In this case low pass filter will give you a set of pulses (beats) in time, so that you can consider whenever a density of these pulses is somehow differs (probably higher) from tune's normal pace - a good chance of being a drum performance. You can also check for higher frequencies if you say other instruments are muted during drums' solo.

Comment: I guess it's possible yes. In which case I apologise for my above comment. Sorry.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? The idea to do this and use it with a massive library of songs just popped into my head and I found this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a FFT is not a good choice for detecting the onset of percussion sounds:

1. An FFT is always calculated over a window of samples (in effect a period of time) and yields the magnitude of signal within the bin and its phase offset.   You can therefore determine that there is signal at that particular bin, but not its onset time.  The best time resolution available is the window period.   Of course, you can make the period shorter at the expense of frequency resolution.
2. Percussion sounds tend to look like noise and spread across the spectrum.  This would be OK if you only had percussions sounds, but is not great in real-life polyphonic content.

However, you might be able to find some inference from the different characteristics of the spectra of a drum solo vs instrumental sections of a track.

The problem of finding the time at which percussion sounds start in music is described in academic journals as *onset dectection* and is one of the many techniques used for *feature extraction*; the wider field is known as *Music Information Retrieval*.    Your problem sounds like one of identifying sections in audio files and this might be described as *partitioning*

A good place to start is [Sonic Visualiser](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org) which is a tool written specifically for MIR applications.  Plug-ins exist for various types of feature extraction.  From these you will be able to easily find the large body of academic work in this area.   There is an added bonus that the existing plug-ins are all open source too.

Comment: Wow, Sonic Visualiser is an excellent tool! Thank you for this comment. I didn't even know it existed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look here, there was a bit of discussion with great pointers on the Gamedev SE: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9761/beat-detection-and-fft :-)

Comment: My question is not related to beat detection.